# git submodule update seems to timeout with no error

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to update git modules, sometimes it works and the modules download, sometimes it seems to timeout and it sits on the same percentage all day! (No error thrown)

Have I missed something in my search for an answer?

```
git clone https://github.com/biometrics/openbr.git
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: It must be something broken on the server, it would be nice to get some feedback though

Comment: I am running iftop to check if there is still traffic from github.com - it might be that the terminal is not refreshing - I am using Linux Mint 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using iftop to see if the connection was still live I discovered that the bash shell was failing to show the finish of the download (and it had actually completed) - I hope this can help someone

Comment: I did have some problems with the download as well